# linq contains string comparison. IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, linq, string-comparison

I want to know if a determind string is in a string list, with the `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` criteria. So I tried something like:

```
bool isInList = _myList.Contains(toFindString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Or:

```
bool isInList = _myList.Contains(listElement => listElement .Equals(toFindString,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

But, the `Contains` method does not contain the `Func<TSource, bool> predicate` overload which I think is the cleanest for this case. The `Where` or the `Count` method for example got it.

Overload method signature for `Count`:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

Specific application for my case:

```
int foundCount = _myList.Count(listElement => listElement.Equals(toFindString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

What would be the cleanest way to add the `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` criteria to the linq `Contains` current overload with the `IEqualityComparer` that is this one `public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer);`?

Comment: `_myList.Any(x => string.Equals(x, toFindString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`?

Comment: wuoo that makes some sense, in `Any` the overload is available...

Comment: There's also [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) which does take an `IEqualityComparer`, which should just work

Comment: but with `IEqualityComparer` you have yo make a class that implements the interface and pass that in, dont you?

Comment: Here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g9Xc1B

Comment: the `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` was what I was missing. I tried to pass that in but was having some errors and did not know how!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got several options.

The first is to use [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0), and test each element using the `string.Equals` overload which takes a `StringComparison`:

```
bool isInList = _myList.Any(x => string.Equals(x, "A", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

(It's safer to use the static `string.Equals(string, string)` where possible, as it's safe to either argument being `null`).

Linq also provides an overload of [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) which takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>`, which you can pass [`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase?view=net-5.0) to:

```
bool isInList = _myList.Contains("A", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

[See here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g9Xc1B).

Answer (score 3):

Either use [`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase?view=net-5.0)

```
bool isInList = _myList.Contains(toFindString, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

or use `Any` with `StringComparison`:

```
bool isInList = _myList.Any(s => s.Equals(toFindString,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

the latter has a problem if there are `null`-strings in the list, so you could use [`string.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-5.0#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_String_System_StringComparison_).

Note that both ways are not suppported with Linq-To-Entities.